# React Native Undefined is not an object - Geolocation

Tags: react-native

I am using Windows 10 and am running an Android 7.0 device.

I am trying to make the device display the lat and long of it's current position using geolocation - when the user pressed a button.

I created a button and made an alert message appear when the user clicked it - so far so good.

Then I tried adding the get current position and then my app crashes with the error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   '_reactNative.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition')

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  Alert,
  Geolocation
} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <Button
          onPress={() => {
            var loc = Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geo_success, [geo_error], [geo_options]);
            Alert.alert(loc);

            //Alert.alert('You tapped the button!');
          }}
          title="Display GPS"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});
```

What does "undefined is not an object" mean, and how do I solve it? (I got the same error earlier, when I tried to access the camera.)

Comment: Add this in your [Manifest](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html#android)

Comment: @PritishVaidya I already have that in my manifest.

Comment: What are you passing in the `geo_success`, `error`?

Comment: @PritishVaidya Probably nothing. I just copied the code I found at: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html

Comment: You need to pass some methods to them, right now the variables are undefined, check some tutorial for help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.geolocation.requestAuthorization')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56908771/typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-navigator-geolocation-request)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update: The feature has been removed from react-native core, so the below answer is no longer invalid.**

The React-Native (v 0.55) Geolocation docs say,

> As a browser polyfill, this API is available through the
> navigator.geolocation global - you do not need to import it.

Don't import  `Geolocation` from `react-native`. Instead use `navigator.geolocation` directly which is a global object.

For example,

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (position) => console.log(position),
  (err) => console.log(err),
  { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 8000, maximumAge: 10000 }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer is no longer accurate. The library has been removed from react-native core, to their community repo.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56909007/4458849