# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.geolocation.requestAuthorization')

Tags: react-native, geolocation

I am attempting to call:

```
`navigator.geolocation.requestAuthorization();`
```

to request geolocation permission.

But, this is resulting in error when running in iOS simulator

This was working at one point, but stopped. I attempted to delete and create a new project. I also tried to uninstall/reinstall node and react-native-cli.

```
import React, {Fragment, Component} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        navigator.geolocation.requestAuthorization();
    }

    render() {

        return (

                <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
                <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
                <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Hello World!</Text>
                </SafeAreaView>
                </View>

                );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  MainContainer :{
     justifyContent: 'center',
     flex:1,
     margin: 5,
     marginTop: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 20 : 0,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: Colors.black,
  },
});
```

I am getting this error:

```
[error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.geolocation.requestAuthorization')

This error is located at:
    in App (at renderApplication.js:40)
    in RCTView (at View.js:35)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
    in RCTView (at View.js:35)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

Comment: _"This was working at one point, but stopped."_ <-- What does this mean? Please include what you changed in-between the working and non-working state. Perhaps you upgraded and now that the [newly release version of React Native v0.60](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/07/03/version-60) moved geolocation to a [separate package](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation), your project no longer has access to the geolocation library and thus you get that error? There are a log of potential errors. You need to include more information.

Comment: I was successfully using the geolocation api and able to get the location. I was continuing on my project, adding more code, then started getting this error. I just installed the react-native stack a few days ago, I had not upgraded anything. I created the attached bare bones code to post here.

Comment: Your comment below indicates that you are on 0.60. Please check the linked package from my previous comment and install it _if you made your project with `react-native init`_. If you did not, please edit your question and include how you setup the new project.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

geolocation has been extracted from react native .60 version. If you need an alternative solution

install react-native-community/geolocation

```
npm install @react-native-community/geolocation --save


react-native link @react-native-community/geolocation
```

then

**IOS**

You need to include the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key in `Info.plist` to enable geolocation when using the app. 
In order to enable geolocation in the background, you need to include the 'NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription' key in Info.plist and add location as a background mode in the 'Capabilities' tab in Xcode.

**Android**

To request access to location, you need to add the following line to your app's `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

**usage**

```
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';

Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(info => console.log(info));
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue, now just gives error: "Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition')"

Comment: which react native version you are using

Comment: if you are keep getting the error try installing react-native-geolocation-service.   link - https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.60.0
npm: 6.9.0
node: 12.5.0

Comment: I could not found any doc which say `geolocation` has been deprecated or extracted, can you provide any links which show it, I only could find the https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation which do not say any thing like you said

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you have added **libRCTGeolocation.a** in Build Phases --> Link Binary With Libraries on your Xcode Project settings and **RCTGeolocation.xcodeproj** under Libraries of your Xcode project.

Answer (score 0):

From RN 0.6 or later, geolocation is not included in the RN core.If you want to use its API, you should do follow the steps in this link: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation

Answer (score 0):

you should use @react-native-community/geolocation

first install it

```
yarn add @react-native-community/geolocation
```

then import

```
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
```

in your function

```
Geolocation.setRNConfiguration(config);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also dealing with the same issue. Later on, I simply changed the package and everything was fine.

```
yarn add react-native-geolocation-service
```

```
// import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
```