# Androidx migration issue with React Native: Not able to build project on android

Tags: android, react-native, androidx

I was using the 0.55.4 version of react native, after androidx update unable to build project on android.

I tried follwing solution:

1. Updates in gradle.properties file:
   android.useAndroidX = true
   android.enableJetifier = true
2. Use Jetifier npm module.
3. Updated React-Native Version to 0.60.0, update classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0' in build.gradle

and all available solution till now but still problem exist.

also tried adding following code in main buil.gradle file

```
subprojects { subproject ->
    if (subproject.name.contains('react-native-datetime-picker') || subproject.name.contains('react-native-geolocation-service')){
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/"  }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Getting following error:

In Android Studio-

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':react-native-geolocation-service@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0.
>   Show Details
>   Affected Modules: react-native-geolocation-service

In VSCode Terminal(when running build through react-native run-android)

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
>   Could not find androidx.appcompat:appcompat:28.0.0.
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>            project :app > project :react-native-splash-screen
>            project :app > project :react-native-geolocation-service
>   Could not find androidx.appcompat:appcompat:28.0.0.
>        Required by:
>            project :app > project :react-native-datetime-picker
>   Could not find androidx.appcompat:appcompat:28.0.0.
>        Required by:
>            project :app > project :Toast
>   Could not find androidx.appcompat:appcompat:28.0.0.
>        Required by:
>            project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.60.0
>   Could not find androidx.appcompat:appcompat:28.0.0.
>        Required by:
>            project :app > project :react-native-image-crop-picker > com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2-native

Comment: are you using geolocation in your project ?

Comment: @sachinmathew, yes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56909007/8977385