# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition is not working in React Native Version(0.60) and above, How to fetch location?

Tags: react-native, geolocation

Trying to fetch current Location using `geoLocation`, it is not working in React Native version(0.60) and above, But it is working in below versions

I realised, `GeoLocation` folder is not there in nodeModules/React-Native/Libraries,
did they remove it from ReactNative(0.60)?

```
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        console.log(position)
    },
    (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),)
```

Getting this error:

> Type Error: Undefined is not an object(evaluating
>   'navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.geolocation.requestAuthorization')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56908771/typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-navigator-geolocation-request)

Answer (score 2):

It seems `geolocation` has been removed from react native .60 version.

Try this:

```
npm install @react-native-community/geolocation --save

react-native link @react-native-community/geolocation
```

You can check this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56908771/typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-navigator-geolocation-request) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

npm install @react-native-community/geolocation --save

react-native link @react-native-community/geolocation

then:

```
import Geolocation form '@react-native-community/geolocation';
Geolocation.etCurrentPosition((position) => {
    console.log(position)
},
(error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error))
```